# plot_tree returns empty chart

Tags: azure-databricks, lightgbm

Working on python azure databricks, I would like to plot a tree (lightgbm) classifier diagram by using plot_tree. Here is what I did and got:

[image]

Apparently, there is no error but an empty chart. I also tried using "create_tree_digraph". Sadly, I can't install graphviz library since after installing by following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/cluster-libraries#install-workspace-libraries all the commands cannot be run. So I've decided to use plot_tree rather than create_tree_digraph.

Comment: you can install python library from inside of notebook using the `%pip install` command

Comment: Unfortunately, that method doesn't work in my case due to working on offline mode.